# Get post meta in the Ajax not working in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am doing an Ajax call and return the value. The post id is coming. But when i tried with this code, It is return blank

```
function visa_status() {
    $postid = $_POST['appid'];
    // args
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => 1,
        'post_type'     => 'cpt_15',
        'meta_key'      => 'application_number',
        'meta_value'    => $postid
    );

    $metaarry = array();
    // query
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $posti = get_the_ID();
    endwhile;

    //echo $posti;
    echo get_post_meta( $posti, 'given_name');
    exit();
}
```

In the above code, $posti is coming. But get_post_meta() is not working.
This is my JS part

```
onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) { 
    if ( newIndex === 1 ) {
        jQuery('.wizard > .steps ul').addClass('step-2');
        appId = jQuery('#appid').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data: {
                'action': 'visa_status',
                'appid': appId,
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('.wizard > .steps ul').removeClass('step-2');
    }
    if ( newIndex === 2 ) {
        jQuery('.wizard > .steps ul').addClass('step-3');
    } else {
        jQuery('.wizard > .steps ul').removeClass('step-3');
    }
    return true; 
},
```

Is there any mistake i have done. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$given_name = get_post_meta( $posti, 'given_name', true );
echo $given_name;
```

OR Try this

```
 echo get_post_meta( $posti, 'given_name', true );
```

[Check here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) what `get_post_meta` function returns based on 3rd parameter.

Comment: Same result. It is coming to response. But not working in console.

Comment: if you are using `dataType: 'json'` , then you need to pass response as `echo json_encode($given_name);` 

or else remove  `dataType: 'json'`